# omitted or not for "the number of "

Tags: articles, numbers, conjunction-reduction

I don't know if the word "number" before "bananas" of the following sentence could be omitted?

"The number of apples is 8 and bananas is 3" or
"The number of apples is 8 and the number of bananas is 3"

Is an article for *apples* and *bananas* needed?
Like "the apples" and "the bananas"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first sentence is the best:

> The number of apples is eight and bananas is three.

No, you do *not* need to repeat "the number of" (although you can if you want to). No, you do *not* need an article before either apples or bananas (although you can if you want to).

This is a style issue, not a rule of grammar: usually you'd want to spell out small numbers like three and eight.

Comment: I'd edit it further to "There are eight apples and three bananas."  It's obvious that eight and three are numbers.